# How do I connect with BigQuery via Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a simple python code which includes connecting with bigQuery using a JSON file having my credentials.

```
data = pd.read_gbq(SampleQuery, project_id='XXXXXXXX', private_key='filename.json')
```

Here the filename.json has the below format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectId",
  "private_key_id": "privateKeyId",
  "private_key": "privateKey",
  "client_email": "clientEmail",
  "client_id": "clientId",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/clientEmail"
}
```

Now, I need to port this code to pyspark. But I am facing difficulties to find how to query using Spark SQL. I am using AWS EMR cluster to run this query!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be great if you could give example code where you tried to connect, and it didn't work.

Comment: You can use the connector https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Comment: The [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) is designed for this purpose, and has a purpose-built [Spark SQL connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector).

Comment: Hi Kenneth this looks really interesting, Can you provide more code example of how this works and how it solves the problem

Comment: There is some documentation in the README.md about how to use the connector with an existing Spark cluster, including scala and pyspark examples. Can you let me know specifically what you're looking for beyond this? I can't help you, but I can likely find someone who can.

Answer (score 2):

Since a SQLContext object is required to use Spark SQL, the SparkContext needs to be configured first to connect to BigQuery. From my point of view, the [BigQuery Connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) (addressed by sramalingam24 and Kenneth Jung) can be used to query data in BigQuery.

Please note that sramalingam24 provided the link with an example, following is a summary of the code:

```
bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
    # Input Parameters.
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'publicdata',
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'samples',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'shakespeare',
}

table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)

word_counts = (
    table_data
    .map(lambda record: json.loads(record[1]))
    .map(lambda x: (x['word'].lower(), int(x['word_count'])))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y))

sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
(word_counts
 .toDF(['word', 'word_count'])
 .write.format('json').save(output_directory))
```

Then you can download the [connector jar for Other Hadoop clusters](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/bigquery#other_sparkhadoop_clusters). And Kenneth Jung provided link with information that suggests that the option --jar can be used to include the connector (--jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar) which is the option to include jar on the driver and executor classpaths.

Answer (score 2):

One of your *submit pyspark* parameters should be *jars* with spark-bigquery-latest.jar package, this is how I added that to dataproc job on google cloud:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar --driver-log-levels root=FATAL script.py
```